# Fresh react-native ios app not building?

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, react-native

Below is the details about my environment and logs of the build failure.
Anyone facing similar issue or know steps to overcome this please do point me out to relevant steps or docs.

- Xcode: 7.2.1
- Node: v5.9.0
- npm: 3.7.3
- react-native-cli: 0.1.10
- react-native: 0.22.2

Running "sudo react-native run-ios" leaves me with the below logs.

LOGS:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/abc/Desktop/REACT-NATIVE/demo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Script-006B79A01A781F38006873D1.sh
(1 failure)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/demo.app
No devices are booted.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
/Users/abc/Desktop/REACT-NATIVE/demo/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/demo.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:469:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:489:13)
    at _runIOS (runIOS.js:83:34)
    at runIOS.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/abc/Desktop/REACT-NATIVE/demo/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/Users/abc/Desktop/REACT-NATIVE/demo/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (/Users/abc/Desktop/REACT-NATIVE/demo/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
    at Array.runIOS (runIOS.js:23:10)
    at Object.run (/Users/abc/Desktop/REACT-NATIVE/demo/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:86:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:73:7)
```

Comment: you already `npm install`, have `flow` and `watchman` in place ?

Comment: yes its installed. flow@0.2.3 and watchman@0.1.8

Comment: Does it work through Xcode?

Comment: I tried building and running via xcode but it too fails via build errors.

Comment: What do you have in Info.plist at `CFBundleIdentifier` ? I think it should be   `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`

Comment: When I open in Xcode it points to your point and resolves it, but still build fails. I'm not able to understand how a new workspace upon just creation fail during build!

Comment: @bala, have you tried my suggestion? feedbacks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have similar issue on OS X El Capitan v10.11.4

```
node --version v6.0.0
npm --v 3.8.8
react-native-cli: 0.2.0
react-native: 0.24.1
watchman --v 4.4.0
xcode 7.3
```

I have created an issue on [react-native github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308).

**I was able to resolve my issue:**

For me port 8081 was in use :

`lsof -n -i4TCP:8081`

`node 7601 arun 23u IPv6 0xc6b249599e5f1169 0t0 TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)`

So I followed the instructions from [React Native Troubleshooting](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html) and killed the pid

`kill -9 7601`

and ran the command `react-native run-ios` again and everything worked as expected (on node 6 as well).

Comment: I was able to solve this issue! For me port 8081 was in use :

`lsof -n -i4TCP:8081`
 `node    7601 CXI624   23u  IPv6 0xc6b249599e5f1169      0t0  TCP     *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)`

So I followed the instructions from React Native Troubleshooting https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html

   `kill - 9 7601` 

and ran the command react-native run-ios again and everything worked as expected (on node 6 as well).

Comment: Thx! Consider editing your accepted answer with info provided in your comment. Cheers.

Comment: not an answer. Move your comment - which is an answer - into the answer, and put your version details into the comment!

Comment: `node 7601 bala 23u IPv6 0xc6b249599e5f1169 0t0 TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)`

getting syntax error near unexpected token `(' in terminal

Comment: @Balasubramanian That's actually the result of running lsof, it's not another command you should be running. From that you can determine which pid to kill

Comment: Note that you need to remove the space between `-` and `9`, so `kill -9 PROCESS_NUMBER`

Answer (score 13):

do not run:

```
sudo react-native run-ios
```

you should run:

```
react-native run-ios
```

your root account does not have Simulator configured properly to run the iOS so you see "No devices are booted" error in your log!

Comment: @bala can you post your output of  react-native run-ios to the question?

Comment: You earned it sir!

Comment: Wonderful answer, I was doing all along sudos and getting into hell of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have a wrong path to the `Developer` directory.

You can check it by running

`$ sudo xcode-select -p`

Unless you really know what you do, it should points to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

If that's wrong, try running this command to fix it:

`$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: abc~/REACT-NATIVE/testingdemo $ sudo xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Its pointing to correct Developer directory only.

Comment: Watch out if you are using XCode Beta - my path was pointing at `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer` but switching back as this answer suggests resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I was having the exact same problem. However, I was using an older version of Xcode (on Yosemite). I had done a complete reinstall of NVM, NPM, and react-native-cli. **Nothing worked**. In doing so, I also followed a guide to ensure that node was uninstalled cleanly before I reinstalled.

What eventually worked was upgrading OSX itself to allow installation of the latest XCode (7.3 at this time). Now it works perfectly. I am able to run `react-native run-ios` from the root directory of my project *without the need for sudo*. As for the sudo issue you might try making sure you are owner of Projects folder. That helped me as well.

So yeah.. I upgraded to OSX 10.11.4 and XCode 7.3. Worked for me.

Good luck.

Answer (score -4):

not sure if this is related but i had to make sure i was on `ruby-2.0.0-p648`
using a newer ruby gave me similar compilation problems.